# Jquery slideToggle effect not smooth and works wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, slidetoggle

```
<style>
   .hideblock{
       dispaly:none;
    }
</style>

<span id="btm">click here</span>

<ul>
    <li id="showid" class="hideblock">
        <span>target text</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $("#btm").click(function(){
        $("#showid").toggleClass("hideblock");
    });
</script>
```

the code works. Now I want close and open it with jquery slide.

I try this:

```
$("#showid").slideToggle().toggleClass("hideblock");
```

this works but very badly.

First, For open: the slide opens buttom to up (not up to buttom)

Second, for close: the slide animation not works!

Comment: Have you got a working example of it not working correctly?

Comment: You do not need to add the hideblock class.  Simply do the slideToggle() function.  This adds/removes "display: none;" as applicable.

Comment: Typo `dispaly`. in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are triggering more than you need to.  Trigger slideToggle() only, don't worry about class toggle.

(also you typo'd in the css display line)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1v15txo/

```
<style>
   .hideblock{
       display:none;
    }
</style>

<span id="btm">click here</span>

<ul>
    <li id="showid" class="hideblock">
        <span>target text</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btm").click(function(){
        $("#showid").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks But I want the slider hidden by default...so how can I do it without class?

Comment: Start it with the hideblock class(as it is now), and fix the typo in the CSS.  Should do the trick.

Comment: thanks. Your code works.but not for me in my html page. maybe because of other js scripts. thanks